# How to automatically exclude maximum and minimum values when calculating an average in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I want to take a medial average, which excludes the highest and lowest values, is there a way to do this on Excel without having to manually find and exclude the highest and lowest values from the calculation of the average?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want exactly? If you have the example data set `{1, 1, 2, 3, 5}`, what numbers do you want to find the average of? `{1, 2, 3}` or `{2, 3}`?

Comment: The OP is a ghost — a brand-new, unregistered user who spent one day on the site (30 days ago), asked this one question (*apparently* without reading the site tour), and hasn't returned.  It seems unlikely that the ambiguity in the question will ever be resolved.

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in function for what you described.  However, it does not require a VBA Macro.  Try the following formula:

```
=(SUM(myRange) - MAX(myRange) - MIN(myRange)) / (COUNT(myRange) -2)
```

Replace `myRange` with the cell range (ie: `A1:A10`).

Answer (score 2):

Steven's answer is great for older versions of Excel.  However, in Excel 2010 and newer (possibly in Excel 2007 as well), the new functions `SUMIFS` and `COUNTIFS` can be used to make a very flexible version of such an average:

[image: Excel snip]

The function for the medial average is:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B7,B2:B7,"<"&LARGE(B2:B7,1),B2:B7,">"&SMALL(B2:B7,1))/COUNTIFS(B2:B7,"<"&LARGE(B2:B7,1),B2:B7,">"&SMALL(B2:B7,1))
```

If you wanted a medial average that excludes more values from the extremes of the list, you would just change the four `1` values within the `SMALL` and `LARGE` functions to match the desired number of values to exclude.

Comment: Using less than and greater than comparison for selecting values to count may do more than what is desired. If the goal is just to exclude the max and min data points (i.e., just two data points), this formula will not perform as expected for data sets where the max or min value appears more than once. For example if the data set is `{1, 1, 2, 3, 5}`, this formula will return the average of `{2, 3}`, whereas @Steven's formula will return the average of `{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: @Excellll, good point. OP will have to clarify which behavior is desired.